# Unable to fetch deta from mongodb in ws02

Tags: wso2

Trying to fetch data from mongodb to ws02 integratoe and gives me output like that
 success details"robust in-only operation"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is unclear, what is the problem here? Did you try anything that you could show us in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

In your "operation" add `returnRequestStatus="true"`.

Example:

```
<operation name="myInsert_operation" returnRequestStatus="true">
        <call-query href="myInsert_query">
            <with-param name="active" query-param="active"/>
            <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
        </call-query>
</operation>
```